# Path . lineTo draws only half of length

Tags: android

Can somebody help me understand how does path.lineTo(x,y) actually work. I am trying to draw a simple straight line in a finger paint type of app. Here is an example I tried:

```
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
            mPath.lineTo(480, 800);
```

But the line goes only from 0,0 to 240, 400 - always only a half of distance as I move my finger over the screen. (the real programme has startX, startY and x,y touch coordinates instead of 0,0 & 480,800)

Comment: Have you set any scale transforms?

Comment: No, and if I just append lines point to point then it works fine just as in finger paint

Comment: So if you use the code above do you get what you expect?

Comment: ie it might be useful to see how you calculate startX, startY and x,y

Comment: I used the code above, to avoid input errors of x, y, and still get half a distance, even with constants!

Comment: Well then I definitely need to see more code because the above just worked fine for me ...

Comment: hahaha .. not sure how i helped you troubleshoot it but you should answer your own question with the solution :)

Comment: After checking everything you said and after you confirmed that it was working well for you, the only thing left was Paint, which I (and others) suspected the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Goz and others who helped me truobleshoot this, it came out that Paint was doing it with this settings:

> mPaint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(1000))

When this is removed or set to null, lineTo goes all the way. One just did not expect at first that Paint would do this but this corner rounding effect can shorten a straight line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this piece of code will work for you:

```
Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
Path mPath= new Path();
mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
mPath.lineTo(480, 800);
p.setColor(0xff800000);
canvas.drawPath(mPath,p);
```

Also, the (480, 800) coordinate, is it still inside your screen?

Answer (score 1):

The `Path` commands work exactly how you expect them to work and the above command should draw a line from top left to bottom righ corners in a view fully covering a 480x800 screen .

Check the follwoing:

- The view covers all screen
- The is no other view overlaping it
- The coordinates are relative to top left coordinate of view. Check that view top left is on top left of screen

Regards.